# Where do I report 1042-S income on 1040 form?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, puerto-rico

US citizen living in Puerto Rico. For 2018 will receive a 1042-S instead 
of a 1099 R for 401 K withdrawals because tax rule changes. My address is Puerto Rico outside 50 states and no W-9 on file.

(My recent research indicates I may need to file 1040 Schedules 1; 4; and 6?)